# Where should I place the score variable when allocating a score to a Model/Object in Ruby/Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model in my Rails app for a SalesOpportunity, and running a SWOT analysis (Strength, Weakness, Opportunity, Threat) to decide how good the SalesOpportunity is. Swots belong_to SalesOpportunities and therefore in the SalesOpportunity Model I have a method called update_swot_score which iterates through the Swot objects and calculates a score based on parameters I'm feeding in. All of this works fine.

What I'm wondering is whether I need to add a field to my SalesOpportunity model (let's call it swot_score for simplicity) and to update the instance variable at the end of the update_swot_score method using @swot_score = "results of my calculation", or whether I can directly access a result of the update_swot_score method (ideally in my view - I'll display different partials depending on the result).

What is the Rails way of doing this? Is there a performance efficiency to be gained by using either method?

Comment: Please format your code with [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: Add a swot_score field in the database and update that field whenever you run update_swot_score method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will suggest to add in the `db` as a **dedicated column** to store `score`...there are few good reasons as why you should do it:-

1. dedicated column to store only `score`
2. easily maintainable even you decide to add/edit new score type in **future**
3. Can be called/updated/modified **anywhere** throughout your application
4. can use **callbacks** in future as well(on_create,on_update) as its in a `Model`
5. Performance wise,its awesome as you can `cache` it..can also `counter_cache` and `expire` too.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks - that seemed like the logical choice but I am new to this and unsure what the best practice is. I'll do as you suggest.